# React for-in loop and map

Tags: reactjs, loops, return, for-in-loop, array.prototype.map

I am working on a react app and I am facing an issue so I would really appreciate some help if anyone can.

I am grouping my data by date, and I have an object that contains the data in this format `{dd/mm/yyyy:[data,data], dd/mm/yyyy:[data,data]}`.

So I am doing a for in loop to loop through the object and then a map to loop through the arrays and then render these, however it seems to stop rendering at the first key-value pair, I am assuming that is because the return statement before the map but the render function doesn't seem to work without it.

Here is my code, any help is highly appreciated.

thanks!

```
  export default class ExpenseMain extends React.Component{

    renderStuff(){
        var expenses = this.props.expenses
        if(Object.keys(expenses).length > 0){
            for(var key in expenses){
                return expenses[key].map((ele,i)=>{
                    return (
                        <div    
                            className = "expensesLoop"
                            key = {i}>
                            <ExpenseItem 
                                expense  = { ele }
                                removeExpense = { this.props.removeExpense }
                                updateExpense = { this.props.updateExpense }
                            />
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    )

                })
            }
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <div>{this.renderStuff()} </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` doesn't return anything.  So, the result will be `undefined`.

Try an `Object.keys().map` instead:

```
        Object.keys(expenses).map(key => {
            return expenses[key].map((ele,i)=>{
                return (
                    <div    
                        className = "expensesLoop"
                        key = {i}>
                        <ExpenseItem 
                            expense  = { ele }
                            removeExpense = { this.props.removeExpense }
                            updateExpense = { this.props.updateExpense }
                        />
                        <hr/>
                    </div>
                )

            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had in fact came up with a similar solution!
:)